# Jasny bootstrap input file implementation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, input, types

I have implemented the Jasny Input File plugin for Bootstrap for a recent project, but I'm not able to make it work according to my UC. I'd like to use the preview functionality that is built in the plugin, but hide it when the page is loaded (in the actual plugin this box is always visible) and when the user clears the input. Besides that, the send image button should remain disabled if no pictures are loaded.

Hope you can help me with this project.

I have a jsfiddle I've been working on without success: http://jsfiddle.net/639Fm/

```
$("input[type="file"]").change(function() {
    var $this = $("#inputtest");
    if ($this.val() == '') { 
        $this.addClass('has-error');
        $(".send-button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(".fileinput-preview.thumbnail").css("display", "none");   
        return false;
    } else {
        $this.removeClass('has-error');
        $(".fileinput-preview.thumbnail").css("display", "block");
        $(".send-button").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");  
    }
});
```

Comment: What's "UC" stand for?

Comment: Hi. UC is Use Case. Sorry for that.